# Flutter ScrollController listener in Nested ListView

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to make ScrollController listener callback when sub ListView nested in ListView?

For Example

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 1000,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: Random().nextInt(10),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          controller: _controller
            ..addListener(() {
              print(_controller.offset);

              /// onScroll
            }),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('$index'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: you are creating n listView views that we need n controllers to listen. I will suggest replace inner list with column if possible and try to use `CustomScrollView` in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, since the items in the list are not fixed. When the user goes to the page again, I have to restore the index and offset of the last position the user viewed.